# PHP array_diff format output

Tags: php, array-difference

I am using array_diff to compare arrays, everything is ok. The format output is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
    [2] => green
    [7] => yellow
)
```

Is there any way to format that output? So I only receive

```
blue
green
yellow
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Save `array_diff` as a new variable and loop through that new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `implode` function instead like as

```
echo implode("<br>",$your_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this :

```
<?php 
$result = array("blue", "green", "yellow");
echo implode("<br>",$result);

?>
```

Comment: didn't thought this before! +1 :D , learning good stuffs from you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array!

```
foreach ($array_diff_output as $arr) {

   echo $arr;
   echo '<br>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop around the array.

```
$data = array("blue", "green", "yellow");
foreach($data as $value) {
   print $value . "<br>"; //use \r and \n if using terminal.
}
```

Result

```
blue
green
yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    explode('<br>', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as someone mentioned already Implode will help

```
<?php 

$data_array = array("blue", "green", "yellow");
echo implode("<br>",$data_array);

?>
```

For your reference: [Implode PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Example: [W3schools reference link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp)